# how to enter values in rowguid column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, guid, ssms

can anyone please tell me the right way to insert values in the rowguid column of the table? I m using sql server management studio

Answer (score 10):

use the [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function to generate one:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(GuidCol uniqueidentifier
                    ,NumCol int)
INSERT INTO myTable Values(NEWID(), 4)
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

or you can set it as a default value:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(GuidCol uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
                    ,NumCol int)
INSERT INTO myTable (NumCol) Values(4)
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Set NEWSEQUENTIALID() as Default in table

```
CREATE TABLE GuidTable
(
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
TEST INT
)
```

Read more about it here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's a [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) column

You can send a value like "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF", or use NEWID/NEWSEQUENTIALID functions to generate one

Answer (score 1):

I was able to insert by using the following:

Insert Into Table FOO(Col1, Col2, RowGuidCol)

Values (5,'Hello,'1A49243F-1B57-5848-AA62-E4704544BB34')

It is very important to follow to place the dashes in the correct place.  You do not need to have the 0x in the beginning of the string.  FYI-Updates are not allow on columns whith the rowguid col property set. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a uniqueidentifier column **rg** in your table **t** which is set to be the rowguid:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE t (rg) VALUES (NEWID())
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TABLE t (rg) VALUES (NEWSEQUENTIALID())
```