# How do I insert data in specific columns in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using the AdventureWorks2012 database...
I created a backup table using the SELECT INTO clause. However, I got an error message when I tried to insert data into some columns using the query below:

```
INSERT   INTO  Sales.salesorderdetails_backup     
                                      (SalesOrderID , 
                                       OrderQty,     
                                       ProductId,   
                                       SpecialOfferId,  
                                       UnitPrice,    
                                       UnitPriceDiscount,    
                                       LineTotal)
                                       OUTPUT  inserted.*
                VALUES (57123,
                         45,
                         712,
                           1,
                        15.89,
                            0,
                         45.89)
```

I got the error msg:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rowguid', table
>   'AdventureWorks2014.Sales.salesorderdetails_backup'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails...

Comment: Maybe here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624681/how-to-enter-values-in-rowguid-column.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your table, you can specify a "not null" constraint for any column or columns. Which means that you *MUST* put a value in that column for any insert.

This is generally a Good Thing.  For example, "not null is the default for a primary key column.

You have two choices:

1) Make sure the column in question has a value before you "Insert" (PREFERRED)

2) Do an "alter table" to drop the "not null" constraint:

`ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn columnType NULL`

ALSO: As you probably know, `NEWID()` is the MSSQL function to generate a GUID for your "insert".

Comment: Or a [default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/ms187872.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a column?

Comment: Yes, "default" is another kind of [SQL constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp), like "not null".  It, too, could solve the problem.  Again, my recommendation is to simply add "Newid()" to the "insert".

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I did use the DEFAULT constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded after I added DEFAULT constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE Sales.salesorderdetails_backup
         ADD CONSTRAINT df_date  DEFAULT GETDATE() for ModifiedDate;
 ALTER TABLE Sales.salesorderdetails_backup
        ADD CONSTRAINT df_guid DEFAULT NEWID() FOR rowguid;
```